# Why Application Servers require stubs to exist in order to do remote calls?

Tags: java, classloader, application-server

It is not a question but a discussion... I don't know if it is the right place, or not..

[As you know, we can write our own java classloaders that can load classes over the network](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=ar&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arabteam2000-forum.com%2Findex.php%3Fshowtopic%3D204370)

So, Why application servers don't just do that? why when we are doing a remote call to a remote method exists inside another application server why we have to have stubs to return types and parameters?

I think application servers can load these return types and parameters remoting using something like `NetworkedClassLoader`.

Comment: If it's truly a discussion and not a question, then it does not belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is what RMI does. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea of the proxy pattern is:

1. to shield clients from the fact that the object they're talking to is not in their address space, it's on a remote server somewhere else on the network.
2. to offload work from the client to server.
3. to centralize an operation into a single service that can be shared by any client that can access the network.

Answer (score 1):

I don't intend to make it a discussion, just to present my view.

The whole point of application server is that work is done on the server. If you load a class `EJBImplementation` on client side and call some of its methods, then work will be done on the client side. Moreover, to do the work properly `EJBImplementation` will have to pull a big chain of dependencies, make some calls to local database and God knows what else. So, in most cases such processing *can't* be done on the client side realistically.

Thus, we create a stub ([proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) is the term) for `EJBImplementation`, which instead passes method invokations over the network to the server.

Comment: You don't get what I mean... I mean why we create stubs ourselves, why not just the client try to get them from the server using some custom classloader? see the link in the edit of `JB Nizet` on my question above.

Comment: @محمد You've asked *"why we have to have stubs"* and got an answer. Also, "we" don't create stubs. Stub objects are created dynamically as proxies. They're *not* loaded from the server, they only make RMI calls to the server.